# MySQL database query INSERT and TRUNCATE

Tags: mysql

How can I solve with query:
I want to calculate out the cubic meter for the whole table in tbale1 and insert the total cubic meter in table2 with the wood type and dimension A. After the data is inserted in to table2 table1 all data need to be cleand out (delet from table).

teble1

| wood | dimension A | dimension B | dimension C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| poplar | 2.5 | 0.5 | 0.029 |
| poplar | 2.5 | 0.35 | 0.029 |

table2

| wood | dimension A | cubic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| poplar | 2.5 | 0.0616 |

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want to calculate the cubic meter for each wood and dimensionA, you can do so while also inserting them into table2 with:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(SELECT t1.wood, t1.dimensionA, ROUND(SUM(t1.dimensionA * t1.dimensionB * t1.dimensionC),5)
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY wood,dimensionA);
```

About the second part (cleaning out the data),I dont really understand the purpose of doing so but you can do it simply by using `DELETE FROM table1`

small [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6ed2b07bc2f10780414ff5e7d0646cd) i used for testing.

Comment: Thx! Works fine! I want to delete the data from table1 what I'am inserting to the table2. Can I put it in to the query "DELETE FROM table1"?

Comment: The query computes the cubic meter for all `woods and dimensionA`  couples, so all the data from `table1` is used, since everything is used you can remove all the rows from `table1` using `DELETE FROM table1`. Now, if you wanted to calculate the cubic meter for a certain group of woods and dimensionA thats another thing, if thats what you wanted i can edit the answer.